# X and X/20 same distribution?

Tags: distributions, self-study

Is it true that if a random variable $$X$$ follows a distribution, say one of these

- Binomial
- Poisson
- Exponential
- Normal
- Uniform

Then $$\frac{X}{20}$$

follows the very same distribution as $X$?

Comment: Depending on what you mean by "very same", the answers are `No, No, No, No, No` or `No, No, Yes, Yes, Yes`

Comment: Think I know what you suggest. Very same is just: follows the same distribution, but not necessarily the same mean and variance.

Comment: Even so, distributions for counts (like binomial, Poisson) are necessarily integers. You could refer to a binomial or Poisson random variable divided by some constant to be *scaled binomial* or *scaled Poisson*. So as Dilip said, for those cases it's still no. Similarly, chi-squared distributions have a particular relationship between mean and variance, so you can't scale them and still have them be chi-squared distributions (but again, you might say 'scaled chi-square' ... or you might say 'gamma').